# Why do we not use oil for the havdalah candle?

Tags: havdalah, oil

Generally it seems to be perferable (mehudar) to use an oil based candle for mitzvot. Why doesn't anyone use an oil based candle for havdalah?

Comment: Why is oil more mehudar for candle based mitzvot aside from Channukah?

Comment: @DoubleAA see question #3 and notes thereon http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5764/chukas.html

Comment: Cos its much easier to send a candle then a bottle of oil!!! http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/mi-yodeya-top-user-swag

Comment: @PM So isn't that your answer?

Comment: What's "an oil based candle"? My _havdala_ candles are [paraffin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraffin)-based: would you consider that "oil based"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mishna Berura 298:5 and Beer Hataiv 298:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=145) mention in the name of the Sefer HaKavonos and the Magen Avraham in the name of the Kavanos HaArizal that it is preferable to use a beeswax candle for Havdala.

As you can see in the Halacha the candle is supposed to be an Avuka - which is more than one wick. This also makes it more practical to use a candle over oil.

Comment: +1 Why [beeswax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beeswax) specifically?

Comment: It does not say the reason. So I would venture to say that it is "Al Pi Kabala".

Comment: I don't see any mention of beeswax specifically in those sources.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127785/what-is-the-reason-for-specifically-using-a-havdala-candle-made-of-beeswax