# Is there a custom to use beeswax candles for Hannukah?

Tags: chanuka, menora-chanukia, bugs

I have heard that there is a custom to use beeswax candles on Hannukah (at least for the shamash). Does this custom have a source? Why beeswax as opposed to other types of wax? [Chabad.org notes](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/chanukah/article_cdo/aid/603798/jewish/Chanukah-Guide.htm)

> The most ideal way to fulfill the mitzvah is with cotton wicks in olive oil, or beeswax candles;

but I was unable to find a proper source. Can anyone shed light on this custom?

Comment: It is from the Arizal - to use something kosher.

Comment: @Yishai - Do you have a written source?

Comment: @Yishai Is paraffin not kosher?

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes it is, but it is a relatively new product. Prior to petrochemical production, tallow based candles were very common (per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_candle_making) tallow or beeswax were the two predominant choices until 1850, the Arizal being about 300 years before that).

Comment: Oren, See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=126&hilite=).

Comment: @Yishai So there is no preference for beeswax.

Comment: @DoubleAA, AFAIK, another material that makes as good or better light and is Kosher is fine. Beeswax is traditional (like the choice of vegetable for Karpas) so will still have preference for that reason. The Netai Gavriel at the above link claims in a footnote that beeswax is preferable Kabalistically over other materials (that are Kosher and make better light), but I have never heard of that before, and he brings no source. Of course it helps to use beeswax so that you know what color your Esrog should be ... ;-).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/21843/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sefer Nitei Gavriel Perek 20:5:note 12 writes that many people use wax for the shamash.
The sources include the Hagaos Maharil,Minhagei Chabad pg 275 since the name wax in Hebrew has connotations to the Holy Names, and besides for the reason it produces a nice light there are kabbalistic reasons as well ,see Magen Avraham siman 288:3 also mentions the Kavanos HaArizal and many Admorim use it.

Comment: "Why beeswax as opposed to other types of wax?"

Comment: דונג which is beeswax = 63 which is one of the Gematrias of Hashem's name - Aruch HaShulachan OC 298:5

Comment: @C.BenYosef - I think your comment warrants a seperate answer since it's the best one yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Orach Chaim 673:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3051) permits all types of wax. I think the reason some use beeswax as opposed to paraffin is due to the nicer light, less dripping, longer lasting, better quality of beeswax candles.

http://www.hiveandhoneyapiary.com/beeswaxvsparaffin.html