# What is the reason for specifically using a Havdala candle made of beeswax?

Tags: minhag, havdalah

The minhag for using Havdala candle made of beeswax is mentioned in [Kaf-Hachaim 298:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.298.12.1?vhe=Kaf_Hachayim,_Orach_Chayim_vol._I-IV,_Jerusalem_1910-1933&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). What is the reason that Havdala candles should specifically made of beeswax? What is the connection between beewax and Havdala?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21842/why-do-we-not-use-oil-for-the-havdalah-candle/21843#comment49545_21843

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we not use oil for the havdalah candle?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21842/why-do-we-not-use-oil-for-the-havdalah-candle)

Comment: Thanks @sabbahillel, but I asked why beewax specifically and not other materials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is beyond my pay grade, but the source that you cite in your question provides the reference that explains the custom (Pri Etz Ḥaim, gate 18, ch. 24).

There, R. Vital teaches that the gematria for *donag* (beeswax) and *sha'ava* (wax) combine to hint at kabbalistic concepts related to the world of Creation (*yetzirah*), which is what the blessing of the havdala light corresponds with. He uses difficult and lofty concepts, that you are "raising the husks" in doing havdala, just like using beeswax for a holy purpose (because it comes from an impure creature?). Heavy material meant for those who understand, so I'll leave the text below:

> שהאדם מדליק האבוקה, יכוין כי דונג גימטריא ס"ג. ושעוה, ר"ל: ש"ע ו"ה, ר"ל ש"ע נהורין דאריך אנפין, הם מאירין לאותיות ו"ה שהם זו"נ, דכתיב בהו עושה גדולות עד אין חקר, עושה היינו שעו"ה. ובכח ש"ע זה, הבדילנו מש"ע קליפין, דכתיב בהו ע"ש תאכלם, היונקים מו"ה. ואו הרים הקליפות, כדונג נמסו מאש הקדוש שבאמא, שבה שם ס"ג, דאלהים מלא ביודי"ן גימטריא ש', וע"ה א"ש. והנה שעוה ודונג גימטר' ד' אלפי"ן מד"ת, כי כן בא"ב דאי"ק בכ"ר, הוא כולה באמא, דאהי"ה ס"ג היינו דונג, ונכללו בה כל שאר המלואים, על סדר זה: אי"ק ע"ב, בכ"ר ס"ג, גל"ש מ"ה, דמ"ת ב"ן. וחוזר למפרע, הנ"ך ב"ן, וס"מ מ"ה, זע"ן ס"ג, חפ"ף ע"ב, וחוזר ביושר, טצ"ץ ע"ב. וכן על דרך זה, וכולם באמא, כנודע דבתר דאולידת הדר אתעברית מינייהו. ועוד כתיב בה, ושמים לא זכו בעיניו. והנה דמ"ת לשם ב"ן שבה, כי עיקר הבדלה בנוקבא שמאלית כנודע. ועוד אל"ף שבס"ג, הוא שורש ומקור לג' אלפי"ן שבמ"ה וארבעתן יחד גימטריא דמ"ת, דהיינו ברך ברך, חד לו וחד לה

Comment: What's the etymology of דונג?

Comment: @DoubleAA: From Klein: Of uncertain etymology; perhaps a loan word from Akka. dumqu (= clear). According to Fleischer related to Arab. danj (= remainder of the honeycombs).

Comment: I haven't done a thorough search, but the few times דונג shows up in Tanakh I'm just seeing it defined in the commentaries as שעוה. How do we know one is beeswax and the other is otherswax?

Comment: They're synonyms in the Tanakh, and Rami bar Avin specifically identifies שעוה as bee material (Shab. 20b), but I believe דונג came to be known as beeswax later, in the Middle Ages (and certainly in Modern Hebrew). Feel free to look into it.